# failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed when accessing from onload method of org.hibernate.classic.Lifecycle

Tags: java, hibernate

## code

**pin** of **l_details** has foreign constraint which refers to **x_details primary key** here i use unidirectional relationship from XDetails class.

## Entities:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "x_details")
    public class XDetails implements Lifecycle {
    private int y;
    ....
    .....
    private Set<LDetails> lDetails = new HashSet<LDetails>(0);
    .........
    ..........
        @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="pin")
    public Set<LDetails> getLDetails() {
        return this.lDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad(Session s, Serializable id) {
        System.out.println("inside  load");
        try{
            if((lDetails!=null)){
                System.out.println("size of lDetails"+lDetails.size());
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    }

    @Entity
    @Table(name = "l_details")
    public class LDetails {

    private Integer id1;
    private Integer pin;
    ....
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id1", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId1() {
        return this.id1;
    }

    public void setId1(Integer id1) {
        this.id1 = id1;
    }
    @Column(name="pin")
    public Integer getPin() {
        return this.pin;
    }

    public void setPin(Integer pin) {
        this.pin = pin;
    }

    }
```

Main thread:

```
    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(XDetails.class);
    criteria.createAlias("lDetails", "status",CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);
    criteria.setFetchMode("status", FetchMode.JOIN); 
    List<XDetails> details=criteria.list();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Exception (inside onload ):

```
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed
    at rg.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.readSize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet.size(PersistentSet.java:162)
    at com.hibernate.test.pendingdict3.XDetails.onLoad(XDetails.java:588)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultPostLoadEventListener.onPostLoad(DefaultPostLoadEventListener.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:898)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:773)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2449)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2192)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2187)
    at org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader.list(CriteriaLoader.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1706)
    at org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl.list(CriteriaImpl.java:347)
    at com.hibernate.test.main4.HibernateStandaloneMain.main(HibernateStandaloneMain.java:24)
```

I am using Hibernate 3.5.6 final dependency, mysql database and I am running hibernatestandalone application.

```
# onload method
       @Override
    public void onLoad(Session s, Serializable id) {
        System.out.println("inside  load");
        try{
            if((lDetails!=null)){
                System.out.println("size of lDetails"+lDetails.size());
            }   
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show us the onLoad method ?

Comment: @overmeulen thansk for seeing this.i already write onload method in XDetails class.

Comment: This is a known problem with Hibernate 3.x. Look at

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977868/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-no-session-or-session-was-closed-desp

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you choose `LAZY` loading but your session is already closed when you first access the elements of your collection. You need to `EAGER` fetch your `Set<LDetails>` or keep your session open until all operations are done.

Comment: i already use fetchmode.join to overwrite annotation settings .see mainthread

Comment: If I'm not wrong, setFetchMode takes a path as parameter, not an alias. So it should be criteria.setFetchMode("lDetails", FetchMode.JOIN) and you can remove your alias.

Comment: k what you said is correct and expected result is coming if i don't access collection inside onload.if i access ldetails inside onload it will again throw the same exception

Comment: If you still get the exact same error it means your collection is still lazily loaded ...

Comment: thank you for reply. i put eager fetching on ldetails ,it fetches the all the details in single query. i am able to read the ldetails after session closed no problem.but if i am reading ldetails in onload of xdetails then i got the exception.

Comment: is there   any additional information you need