# Merge and saveOrUpdate of updated entity throws constraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate, scala

```
I have an entity which contains a Map:

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinTable(name = "matrix_columns", joinColumns = Array(new JoinColumn(name = "id")))
  @MapKey(name="tenor")
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
  @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
  def getInputMapNative: java.util.Map[Int,Column] = inputMap
```

And the Columncontains an Array

```
  @(OneToMany @field)(cascade = Array(CascadeType.ALL))
  @OrderColumn(name = "input_index")
  @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
  var inputs:Array[Input] = _
```

Because I am stucked with Hibernate 3.6 and of this bug [Failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or session was closed (despite eagerly fetching)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14977868/failed-to-lazily-initialize-a-collection-no-session-or-session-was-closed-desp), I tried to implement as a workaround the following:

- I merge and save the columns
- I update the map and merge and save the parent entity

(Since I can't rely on Hibernate cascading)

However, I still get an exception which I am not ready to solve

```
09:41:26.160 [GS-Notifier-pool-6-thread-2] ERROR o.h.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Duplicate entry '781' for key 'inputs_id'
09:41:26.167 [GS-Notifier-pool-6-thread-2] ERROR o.h.e.d.AbstractFlushingEventListener - Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert collection: [Column.inputs#69]
```

This is my code that I would like to use both for creating or saving a new matrix in the database

```
val mergedColumns = matrix.getInputMap.map {
                              case(tenor,column) =>
                                column.inputs foreach{
                                  item =>
                                    val mergedItem = session merge item
                                    session saveOrUpdate mergedItem
                                }
                                (tenor, (session merge column).asInstanceOf[Column])
                            }
  matrix.setInputMapNative(mergedColumns)
  val mergedMatrix = session merge matrix

  session saveOrUpdate mergedMatrix

  transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is related to the uniqueness of the primary key inputs_id. Hibernate tries to insert the same entry twice, so I guess your way to merge and save the columns and update the map is the problem here.

Please consider Session.saveOrUpdate.

To get a better answer, please provide additional information like the code snippet you use to insert the new entry.

Comment: Does those elements have the id pre-set? What are the annotations of the id field?

Comment: Does those elements have the id pre-set? Since you are using merge it seams that those enities are from within another session. Try to switch from saveOrUpdate to simply use only update on those merged items. It seams hibernate is trying to reinsert the merged items on session saveOrUpdate mergedMatrix or even on the session saveOrUpdate mergedItem.

Comment: I do not think this is a good solution. You should figure out why Hibernate is trying to reinsert your entities. You might run into the same problem again later on. Maybe you can solve it be even do not use a saveOrUpdate on single merged entities but I have a different hint for you.

Think about your session settings. Is your session on autocommit? Are you using a stateless session (that would also explain what you see)? Also you should set logging to debug level, so you can why Hibernate is reinserting the entity.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. No it's a stateful session... and the problem comes with detached entities...