# get List object HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, lazy-initialization

I have a mother Class (SchemaBase) containing  a list of CubeBase so i wannt to recuperate that list of CubeBase containing the id of SchemaBase:

```
public List<CubeBase>listCube(){

    listCubeSchema.addAll(cubeService.listcubeByIdSchema(shmanged.getSchema().getId_schema()));

    return listCubeSchema;

}
```

and i write this code in managedBean:

```
public List<CubeBase>listCube(){

        listCubeSchema.addAll(cubeService.listcubeByIdSchema(shmanged.schema.getId_schema()));

        return listCubeSchema;

    }
```

i get this error:

```
15:27:24,159 Avertissement [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8383-4) #{xmlMan.GenerateXml()}: 
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: esprit.olap.domain.CubeBase.namedSets, no session or session was closed:
```

this is the Cubebase class:

```
public class CubeBase implements Serializable{

    /**
     * Private Attribute 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;




    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_cube;

    private String name_cube;

    private String description_cube;

    private String caption_cube;

    private boolean visible;

    private boolean cache;

    private boolean enabled;



    @ManyToOne
    private SchemaBase schema;


    @OneToMany (mappedBy="cube",cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<NamedSetBase> namedSets;

    @OneToMany  (mappedBy="cube",cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<MeasureBase> measures;

    @OneToMany  (mappedBy="cube",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<DimensionBase> dimensions;

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private ViewBase view;

    ....
}
```

and this is the SchemaClass:

```
public class SchemaBase implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id_schema;  

    private String name_schema;

    private String description_schema;

    private String measuresCaption_schema;

    private String defaultRole_schema;


    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private CatalogBase catalogBase;




    @OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<CubeBase>cubes;

    @OneToMany (cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.ALL}, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<ParameterBase>parameters;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<DimensionBase> dimensions;
....}
```

but she doesn't work to me even i think it's not right so can you help me plz and i don't why the problem is from other class (NamedSet) !!

Answer (score 1):

see this example:

```
public List<User> getUsers() {
    Query qry = getSession().createQuery("from User u order by upper(u.username)");
    return qry.list();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<CubeBase> listCube=ent.createQuery(from CubeBase);
```

To study about writing a query in hibernate refer this link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

Answer (score 0):

This work for me :

```
final String sql="your hql request";
List<AAA> aaas =  getSession().createQuery(sql).list()
```

Comment: the problem is in the hql query !!

Comment: Sorry, your problem can be solved this link : 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15089706/4017037

Answer (score 0):

you can get your session with sessionFactory.getCurrentSession() then you use this session for create your queries.